# Is there a Grok pattern at logstash for following Dateformat? Wed Apr 01 23:29:47.834 2020

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Hy, I have following time-format: Wed Apr 01 23:29:47.834 2020
I don´t get it, how to handle this with grok in logstash.
I really hope, someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **logstash** patterns documentation [here](https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns) you can use **HTTPDERROR_DATE**.
The other option could be `%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}`

I tried with online grok [pattern matcher](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/) and both works for me.

Pattern supplied for test: `Wed Apr 01 23:29:47.834 2020`

Comment: Thank you very, very much. It is working now :)

Comment: @Clies If it works for you, can you please accept the answer.